# React with AppSync websocket failed

Tags: javascript, websocket, aws-appsync

I have a React app with AWSAppSync.

This has been running with AppSync for 1 year. Yesterday, in the local environment (locahost:3000) I run a function that calls some endpoints that are Lambda functions. I don't know what happened, but this is the first time that, for some reason, the app gets stuck. I had to close Chrome, and when I opened again the app, the console in chrome shows me these errors:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://XXX(hidden, just for the question)-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=XXX%XXX%2Fus-east-1%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200214T120942Z&X-Amz-Expires=3600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=XXX&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEL3%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%XXX%2...Iqt%2FYbC1VcHYZvvirJEBsuewBbuWnsCopy%2BPVIKwD9dkKW983Lk7AVO3H8sJ4SXQ%2FAfdFXygrzPWx7HnAy0rWB%2FUu89w4XJg07obTA8xkVs5HakFFVrXbd1EFgEWy8tcz2dS4Wn2hfvdkNs149uAkhoO0lbahPCK3dVYKaS6vWS5bLEjN1swhpya8gU61gEN3PDr1OyDDCc%2F7pxYE%XXX%2BoP%2B7%2FqV0OTK%2B0%XXX%2BcZhgr7LkAjgG3sBho1s65ietLymn1355%2F3z2PglnETpHh9FTnHUBxPl6kajt1MBvaZTkcQp5ks7FJ21KshW2hj89cYv94cRr5xXlsw8DKc44rh%2BJpOZgNmMYWHGKnbFR%2B%XXX%2Flm3TSLzTERGwHAoJ' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

The console looks like this:

[image]

I tried to close the server (stop `yarn start`), even restart windows, nothing happened, now every time that I join the app I get those messages in the console. It's always the same number, it happened those 10 times and stops. So, the weird thing (or maybe not so weird) is if I open the production environment, not localhost, I get the messages too. If someone runs their local environment of opens the production environment it doesn't happen to him, only in my pc. Everyone shares the same public IP, so I don't get it.

Should I see in AWS console if some Lambda function is running or something like that? I just use endpoints for lambda functions, I never join the AWS console tho.

What else should I look to stop those messages? the app gets really slow with those messages, plus, in the network tab I get this:

[image]

Seriously, don't know what could be.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was outside the app. The VPN where I work was blocking some ports and protocols... that was all.